# Creating and App using PHP, Mysql, and jquery and i am stuck

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to create an app that writes a basic music chord chart to a database and pulls it out onto a different page.
I know the basic to intermediate concepts of inserting and returning data to a database but I am having trouble on this one.

In a textarea I would like the member to be able to insert into the database like so...

```
{C}I`ve {F}been {G}though {A}the {C}desert
```

The Letters inside the brackets being the chords and the words outside of the brackets being the lyrics.
This is not the problem though, I know how to do that.

The problem is, **I would like the {Chords} to be placed directly above the letter they are preceding while also giving them a class that would allow me to change the font color, size, and weight when rendered on page.**

I have been thinking that there is a way to do this with tables, str_replace, and strTok but I cannot figure it out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you mention jQuery? Do you need help with anything relating to jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

- use regular expression to extract content of {} into an array
- str_replace {} to blank (space), in a way you will have plain text except chords letter
- use html css, put Chords letters in span tag.change css of span, so it position above the letter. i.e. span position is absolute and parent container position to relative.
- if you want to save those chords into table , you can as its already in array

Hope this helps, best of luck

Comment: Thanks I'll try this and let you know if I have problems. I'll take any other suggestions if anyone else has an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Working with HTML tables can be a real pain. Here's how you could do the HTML part of it without using tables:

```
<style>
.phrase { display: inline-block; }
.chord { font-size: 20px; }
.lyrics { font-size: 12px; margin-right: 1em; }
</style>

<div class="phrase">
    <span class="chord">C</span><br>
    <span class="lyrics">I've</span>
</div>
```

And with a little PHP mixed in:

```
<?php
$phrases = array(
    array('chord' => 'C', 'lyrics' => "I've"),
    array('chord' => 'F', 'lyrics' => 'been'),
);
?>
<?php foreach($phrases as $phrase): ?>
<div class="phrase">
    <span class="chord"><?php echo $phrase['chord']; ?></span><br>
    <span class="lyrics"><?php echo $phrase['lyrics']; ?></span>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

As far as saving/retrieving from the database. You could do some fancy regular expression/string replace thing, but that's probably more work than you really need to do. Just keep it simple and create a structure like this:

```
Songs           Example
---------       -----------
id (PK)         1234
song_title      I've been through the desert

Phrases
-----------
id (PK)         1
song_id (FK)    1234
chord           C
lyrics          I've
order           1
```

You'll have a lot more rows in your `Phrases` table, but it will be a lot easier to work with.

Also, as a final, biased, piece of advice: check into [Ruby on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/). I started out learning PHP and wished I would have learned Ruby on Rails earlier in my career. There are a lot of ways that Ruby on Rails makes it easy for a beginner to get started programming.